# Get current VirtualBox Status with Vagrant

Tags: virtualbox, status, vagrant

We did alot of stuff with Vagrant in the recent days, and there's a problem we encountered / didn't find any answer to. It's about checking the Status of the VirtualBox with Vagrant, for example:

```
if config.vmbox_status == 'running'
  # do this stuff
end
```

If there is any easy way of checking / getting the current Virtual Box status let us know.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to check running status with shell script. Try this code inside your project folder

```
vagrant status --machine-readable | grep state,running
```

Then check output string or exit code

Comment: This works for me and will have an exit code of 0 if state is running, and 1 otherwise, so can be used in my script which checks status.

Comment: `--machine-readable` does not seem to be available in current Vagrant versions

Comment: @AdN Which vagrant version do you use? According to [official document](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/machine-readable.html) This argument should be there when vagrant version >= 1.4

Comment: My bad, it is there indeed! Have a +1 for the noise ; )

Answer (score 4):

You can use `egrep` to get current status (other answers check for certain statuses while this approach allows you to use `case` or `if` in scrips, like that (ugly and not-bullet proof!):

```
VM_STATUS=$(vagrant status --machine-readable | grep ",state," | egrep -o '([a-z_]*)$')
case "${VM_STATUS}" in
  running)
     echo "RUNNING"
  ;;
  poweroff)
     echo "POWEROFF"
  ;;
  *)
     echo "Unhandled: ${VM_STATUS}"
  ;;
esac
```

Comment: Add underscore to `([a-z]*)`, e.g. `([a-z_]*)` such that `not_created` does not yield `VM_STATUS = created`.

Answer (score 0):

Or with the use of **awk** to get the VM's current state:

```
VM_STATUS=`vagrant status --machine-readable | grep ",state,"  | awk -F, '{print $4}'`
case "${VM_STATUS}" in
  running)
     echo "RUNNING"
  ;;
  poweroff)
     echo "POWEROFF"
  ;;
  *)
     echo "Unhandled: ${VM_STATUS}"
  ;;
esac
```

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure if you want to do this within Vagrantfile necessarily but outside of it you can fire command `vagrant status BOX_NAME` and get the status of box. You will get text in following format:

```
Current VM states:
box2                     running
```

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't work for me outside of the folder with Vagrantfile. It says: `$ vagrant status box_1-lucid64
A Vagrant environment is required to run this command. Run 'vagrant init'
to set one up.`

Comment: @WojciechBednarski As of May 2014, this feature is now available if you still need it.  See my answer.

Answer (score -3):

change directory to location of VM: `cd d:/vagant_boxes`

run: `vagrant status`